# What is this "ever?"

Tags: grammar

> "the vain notion that there could **ever** be an easy, painless catholicon for obesity…"
>   from Webster

What is this **ever**?

Answer (score 1):

Quite literally, what it appears to be.

Read it as

> "the vain notion that there could - at any time, past, present or the far technological future - be an easy, painless catholicon for obesity…"

ever = always & forever.
Doesn't always have to include the past, it could merely indicate a 'wishful future' - as your example appears to be about to tell us that someone did manage to invent a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It means **'as if possible'**

See this sentence

1. John has this weird notion that he could ever be a millionaire.

(The person saying this doesn't believe that John could ever become a millionaire. He doesn't believe that John becoming a millionaire is ever possible)

In your example it means that

An easy, painless catholican for obesity could never be possible. (And is never going to be possible - according to the writer of the sentence)

```
'ever' can be replaced by 'never'.
```

But the meaning here will be **'as if impossible'**

See the examples.

1. He talks like there could never be any hope of his life to get better.

(Means there could be hopes for his life to get better but he believes that there are no hopes at all)

2. She talks like she could never be wrong as a judge of character.

(It means there will be times when she will make a mistake while judging a character, but she does not believe that. It's kind of over-confidence.)